# Looking for simulation corner model of 230VAC lines

Tags: ac, transformer

I'm searching some sort of worst case model of the main electricity 230V-AC.
The most simple source is a sine with 50Hz and 325V peak.

But we could have disturbance on the main electricity, and I'm also interested to know if there is a sort of list with "corner model" that can happen?

I can give one disturbance case: Imagine a high power load controlled by a triac (that switch on/off properly at 0 current/voltage). Because the line have a resistance and an inductance, the switch on/off of a high power load will have an impact on the main electricity voltage (325V could become 320V or worst?). If this load is connected an odd number of times, then the injected disturbance will generate a sort of DC voltage/current on all transformer connected on the main electricity line. I want to simulate this with LTspice.

After my example, is there a database of corner model (with this type of disturbance) that can happen on the 230V-AC? A sort of international standard where all tools connected on electrical outlet should pass?

Comment: Worst case is a lightning strike.

Comment: Power Line quality standards in books define the test criteria in IEC, IEEE, ANSI, CSA pick one.  The models are different for lightning surge withstanding and dielectric withstanding, V surge, dropout and tolerance etc But if you are in a country with poor regulated power, good luck http://www.powerstandards.com/IEC.php

Comment: http://apqi.org/application-note/voltage-fluctuations-in-power-networks-flicker/

Comment: There are millions of reports on this subject and hundreds of standards.  A naive simple model does not exist, but this research with DC has been done many times.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely be better off trying to decide what types of power line disturbances you want to be immune to then arrange your simulation environment to inject those types of disturbances.

As a guide you could look at what the legal requirements are for agency certified product testing in your region of the world. These requirements will have immunity specifications that detail the minimum levels of disturbances that your product must survive and remain functional. Note that in most cases there are various types of products that fit into classification categories that will have varying levels of minimum requirements.

Once you understand the minimum requirements you will decide how much additional margin you want to design and test to. In addition you may decide to add additional types of requirements to focus on increased robustness for your product.

Once you have the targets understood it is not complicated to add sources into your model to inject each type of disturbance. For voltage types you can simply connect voltage sources in series. For current types you can put sources in parallel. For example if one of your requirements is to survive injected spikes on the power line up to 1200V peak at 1usec width you just create a source that is configured to produce a single or repetitive 1usec pulse with amplitude of 1200V. This source will simply add to the voltage being produced by the sine wave source that represents the AC mains.

You can also add series resistors into the simulation to show realistic real world circuit characteristics. Similarly small capacitors can be added between circuit nodes to simulate real world coupling.